# Why the the isSameMethod() returning true for paths that are not the same?

Tags: java, path, nio

```
try {
System.out.println(Files.isSameFile(Paths.get("/user/home/cobra"),
Paths.get("/user/home/snake"))); //line 1 outputs true

System.out.println(Files.isSameFile(Paths.get("/user/tree/../monkey"),
Paths.get("/user/monkey"))); //line 2 outputs true

System.out.println(Files.isSameFile(Paths.get("/leaves/./giraffe.exe"),
Paths.get("/leaves/giraffe.exe"))); // line 3 outputs true


} catch (IOException e) {
// Handle file I/O exception...
}
```

In the code above I was expecting the output to be false for line 1, line 2 and line 3 since the path are not the same, but it true for all of these instance, can someone please explain why is this?

Comment: on unix systems (and on windows too, but its not so easy) you can create symbolic links. It means that file at path X is the same file in other path

Comment: Can't reproduce the first.

Answer (score 2):

You don't check if the path is the same but if your paths are evaluated to the same file. And for your second and third example, these are paths to the same file.

Your first example is out of the line (I can't reproduce it). But you may have a linked file `cobra` that links to the other file or vice versa. So that could explain why both paths are evaluated to the same file. But if both are different files or folders, your first example should print `false`.

Comment: I am doing examples from the OCP book and it is stated the reason for the first example being true is "Since cobra is a symbolic link to the snake file, the first example outputs true."  and you also state in you answer "may have a linked file cobra that links to the other file or vice versa" ? What do you mean by this?

Comment: You also say that " You don't check if the path is the same but if your paths are evaluated to the same file", but I have placed the same file in the directory "C:\\Users\\shalotte1\\Documents\\cobra"  and "C:\\Users\\shalotte1\\Documents\\snake" it is still outputing false

Comment: No, it does not validate the content of the file but the file the paths leads you to.